# Tag suggestion for search or search by tag

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

Today I wanted to search questions related to `AsyncTask` in Android. I searched [android-async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-async) (yeah, I'm lazy, I know that's not the right tag) and after getting no results, I found out that the right tag to search for is [android-asynctask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-asynctask). How? By typing "async" in the favorite tags add text box which gives suggestions:

[image]

So, I think having this suggestion feature for search would be really useful. Or better having the option of search-by-tag that would work just like the above mentioned text box.

Comment: 8 years later still no tags suggestion in search field...